# Расчет pts dts и duration FFmpeg и C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoder

есть вектор, который содержит кадры и временные метки, соответствующие кадру:

```
std::vector<std::pair<QByteArray, int64_t>> rawData;
```

Кадры это просто `QImage`.
Временные метки получаются так:

```
const int64_t timestamp = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
```

Настройка контекста:

```
pCodecCxt->time_base = AVRational{1, m_fps};
pCodecCxt->framerate = AVRational{m_fps, 1};
```

как правильно вычислить с учетом временных меток кадра?:

```
pkt.pts = ?;
pkt.dts = ?;
pkt.duration = m_currentFrameTimestamp - m_previousFrameTimestamp;
```

**UPD:**

Итак, зная метки кадров, я могу вычислять продолжительность кадра и начало каждого кадра.

```
int64_t frameTime;
int64_t frameDuration;
int count = m_frameCounter++;

frameDuration = m_currentFrameTimestamp - m_previousFrameTimestamp;
frameTime = count * frameDuration;

pkt.pts = frameTime;
pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
pkt.duration = frameDuration;
```

Остался вопрос по поводу настройки контекста tame_base. Так как временные метки в миллисекундах, то видимо должно быть так:

```
pCodecCxt->time_base = AVRational{1000, m_fps};
```

**UPD**:
Это по прежнему не работает.

```
int64_t frameTime;
int64_t frameDuration;
int count = m_frameCounter;

frameDuration =  (m_currentFrameTimestamp - m_previousFrameTimestamp) / (1000 / 60);
frameTime =  count * frameDuration;

pkt.pts = frameTime;
pkt.dts = pkt.pts;
pkt.duration = frameDuration;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**time_base** - задает базовую единицу измерения времени как дробь, где в числителе стоит количество тактов, а в знаменателе - частота тактового генератора (например 2997);

**pts** - Presentation Time Stamp - время показа кадра в базовых единицах;

**dts** - Decoding Time Stamp - время декодирования опорного кадра (который требуется для отображения текущего) в базовых единицах; может совпадать с pts если текущий кадр - опорный;

**duration** - продолжительность отображения кадра в базовых единицах;

Comment: т.е. pts = (1/fps) * fps?

Comment: @SergeyZinovev нет, по такой формуле pts будет всегда равен 1, вам надо timestamp кадра разделить на time_base, заданный в тех же единицах, что и timestamp

Comment: я использовал такую формулу av_rescale_q(m_currentFrameTimestamp, AVRational{1 / 1000}, AVRational{1 / m_fps}); 1000 потому что timestamp в миллисекундах. видео все равно некорректное. Очень быстро, за секунду проигрывается от начала до конца, хотя там кадров много.

Comment: возможно я вас неверно понимаю. Я не могу правильно настроить. Вы не могли бы привести пример кода? Буду очень признателен, чтобы я копипасту сделал, и посмотрел

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Ну вот если у вас 60 кадров в секунду и time_base 1 / 60, pts у кадров будут идти подряд 0 1 2 3 4...

Comment: А как считать? И контекст настраивать. У меня fps 60, а метки в миллисекундах

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Это же начальная школа. Если время в миллисекундах, то чтобы получить из них единицы time_base, их необходимо разделить на количество миллисекунд в одной time_base. `ms / ( 1000 / 60 )` → `( ms * 60 ) / 1000`

Comment: Что то не работает. По прежнему и продолжительность и скорость видео не удовлетворительные

Comment: @SergeyZinovev Так это все-таки правильный подход был, или в чем была проблема?

Comment: В целом все, что вы описали верно. Однако помогло другое решение. Именно:pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pVideoCodec->coded_frame->pts, pVideoCodec->time_base, pStream->time_base); и возведение флага pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

Comment: скажите, вы не могли бы мне помочь с другим моим вопросом, возможно вам было бы интересно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237154/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%8d%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-wasapi-%d0%b2-avframe-ffmpeg-c